# React Native Image source not display

Tags: react-native

I have a few favicon images can not be displayed using Image uri, some are working.
Here are some favicon that I can't display on the device,
https://www.sitepoint.com/favicon.ico,
http://static.hdslb.com/images/favicon.ico

Anyone know why?
Thanks

Comment: Please display the code that isn't working.

Comment: @whs.bsmith, <Image source={{'https://www.sitepoint.com/favicon.ico'}}

Answer (score 0):

If you hook to the onError callback, you'll get details in `{nativeEvent: {error}}`.

For favicons.ico with mime type image/x-icon I got the error `"unknown image format"`.

This would indicate that Fresco cannot handle these types of images. Might be simpler to copy the icons, convert them to PNG and host them elsewhere.